# How disable cursor shape modes in neovim?

Tags: neovim, cursor

*Hello, so I just posted an issue in neovim's officiall github repo about a problem I am going to tell you about in a couple seconds and after finding a solution they told me the instructions were outdated and so they redirected me here...*

My issue is that...being a vim user I got used to the deafult cursor shape which is the default terminal one but after switching to neovim I've realised that when I switch to insert mode the shape of my cursor switches to such a gui cursor or a vertical bar which don't get me wrong...it is a really cool feature and thing to have but I don't particulary like it so I've been trying to remove or disable it.

According to [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/5977#issuecomment-372105560) thread which is the one I was talking about the solution was that I change the value of **NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE** 
to **0** but apperantly that is **outdated** so I would like to get some help from this forums. Some more information about neovim and terminal you can find below and and help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Neovim Version 0.2.2
URXVT Version 9.22
Operating System : Manjaro i3 4.12.24-1
```

Edit: Ashok recommended so I better visualize my problem with some pictures so here they are...
The deafult cursor I would like to have which is the one you get on vim as well is
[image: this]
 and I want that to not change in all modes...however when I switch to insert mode in neovim it changed the cursor to some sort of vertical shape like
 [image: this].
 Hope I made it easier to understand!

Comment: Include few pictures to better explain your problem, it's hard to visualize from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-change-cursor-shape-in-the-terminal), prior to version 0.2 cursor shaping was only enabled if `$NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE` was set.

Starting with 0.2, the `'guicursor'` option took over this functionality, so that the behavior could be consistent among UIs.

- For Neovim < 0.2, don't set `$NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE` if you don't want cursor shaping
- Otherwise, put `set guicursor=` in your init.vim to disable it